# n to n entity framework relationship

Tags: .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first, entity-relationship

I'm creating my code first app, and I got stuck.

I have a model called Professional and another called Skill.

Here I have a "n to n" relationship, and when i create my database from this model,

I got a table called "SkillModelProfessionalModels" that has a compound primary key (Skill_Id + Professional_Id)

I want to create a non compound PK at "SkillModelProfessionalModels" and got something like this:

```
SkillModelProfessionalModels_ID
SkillModel_ID
ProfessionalModelID
```

any idea?

Thanks

Comment: What's the point of the non-compound primary key here?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to create the intermediate table which holds many to many mapping.

Please take a look at [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/234606/Creating-a-Many-To-Many-Mapping-Using-Code-First) article. I am sure you will get what you want.